# Cannot set monitor preferences on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 + lightdm

Tags: multiple-monitors, lightdm, ubuntu-mate

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on my laptop (Lenovo G50). 
I have an external monitor attached to it and I would like to set it as the primary screen. 
Also, my laptop is on the right of the external screen and I would like to set this too (i.e. I want to move to the laptop screen by moving my mouse to the right and not to the left).

I opened the monitor preferences to fix this but I cannot apply those settings.

I'm using lightdm

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

My `monitors.xml` seems fine:

```
cat ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Gives

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="eDP-1">
          <vendor>LGD</vendor>
          <product>0x044b</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1366</width>
          <height>768</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>1680</x>
          <y>282</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-1">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-1">
          <vendor>GSM</vendor>
          <product>0x5677</product>
          <serial>0x000253fd</serial>
          <width>1680</width>
          <height>1050</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-2">
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

And I also copied this file to `/var/lib/lightdm/.config/monitors.xml`.

Up until recently everything worked well and, apparently, a recent software update is the cause for this problem.

How can I fix this?

Thank you,
Gilad